# how to set 00:00:00 for DateTime

Tags: php

What I want to get are

- today's 00:00:00
- week start day's 00:00:00
- month start day's 00:00:00
- year start day's 00:00:00

So I write the code,

```
$today = new \DateTime();
$weekStart = new \DateTime();
$monthStart = new \DateTime();
$yearStart = new \DateTime();

$weekStart->modify('last sunday');
$monthStart->modify('first day of this months');
$yearStart->modify('first day of this year');

print $today->format('Y-m-d h:i:s')."\n";
print $weekStart->format('Y-m-d h:i:s')."\n";
print $monthStart->format('Y-m-d h:i:s')."\n";
print $yearStart->format('Y-m-d h:i:s')."\n";
```

It gave me the result:

> 2018-11-13 09:34:02
>   2018-11-11 12:00:00
>   2018-11-01 09:34:02
>   2018-11-01 09:34:02

I have two questions.

How can I make each `DateTime` 00:00:00??

How can I get the first day of year???

Comment: `new \DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:00');`

Comment: Since you're using *keywords* anyway something like this would work: `new DateTime('midnight last sunday', new DateTimezone('UTC'));` - just add in the *midnight* keyword basically.

Comment: I think you missed [DateTime::setTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php).

Comment: You're using a 12hr time string (`h:i:s`) in the `format()` method - because of this it'll display `12:00:00` instead of `00:00:00` - use `H:i:s` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP's date parsing is somewhat tricky. Here's the code snippet which does what you want:

```
$today = new \DateTime('midnight');
$weekStart = new \DateTime('midnight last sunday');
$monthStart = new \DateTime('midnight first day of this month');
$yearStart = new \DateTime('midnight first day of january this year');


echo $today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
echo $weekStart->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
echo $monthStart->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
echo $yearStart->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
```

- `DateTime` value can be set upon construction; there's no need to call `DateTime::modify()`.
- Add `midnight` to get the time set to `00:00:00`.
- **`first day this year` doesn't work in PHP, you need to use `first day of january this year` instead.**

Reference: [PHP Documentation of relative date formats.](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Comment: It's possibly worth considering setting the timezone to `UTC` unless you've got a good reason to use local time - Daylight Savings makes life difficult otherwise; especially with `midnight`

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
$date->setTime(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you it also helps my issue setTime

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-07-22');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
```

NO need to create a object of datetime(), use above code to get current date with time 00:00:00

Comment: Thanks However I would like to use DateTime consistently for whole source code.